From mobile side the the virtualBackground is getting streched?
I'm using the Twilio library for video calling and have implemented functionality to add a virtual background behind the video track. Initially, I used OffscreenCanvas, but it's not supported in Safari. Therefore, I switched to the WebGL pipeline. However, I encountered an issue where the fitType property doesn't apply when using WebGL. This causes the background to appear stretched when applied from mobile devices. Is there a solution to ensure the background looks properly contained across all operating systems and browsers?
  const initializeVirtualBackgroundProcessor = (
    videoTrack: LocalVideoTrack | RemoteVideoTrack,
    backgroundUrl: string
  ) => {
    const img = new Image();

    img.onload = () => {
      const newProcessor = new VirtualBackgroundProcessor({
        assetsPath: '/',
        backgroundImage: img,
        debounce: true,
        pipeline: Pipeline.WebGL2,
        fitType: ImageFit.Contain
      });

      newProcessor
        .loadModel()
        .then(() => {
          if (virtualBackgroundProcessor) {
            videoTrack.removeProcessor(virtualBackgroundProcessor);
          }
          videoTrack.addProcessor(newProcessor, {
            inputFrameBufferType: 'video',
            outputFrameBufferContextType: 'webgl2'
          });
          setVirtualBackgroundProcessor(newProcessor);
          setVirtualBackgroundApplied(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(
            'Error initializing virtual background processor:',
            error
          );
        });
    };

    img.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('Error loading background image:', error);
      // Handle error loading image, maybe fallback to default or show an error message
    };

    img.src = backgroundUrl;
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  };

The top one is from PC and the bottom one is from mobile

